# Azure Wordpress stops working when dealing with big files

Tags: wordpress, azure

I have a problem with my Azure WP installation.
Though I edited the .user.ini file and can see that I can upload files up to 512M, the admin-ajax stops working (404 not found) when posting big files in Media gallery or while importing a 60M backup from All-in-One WP Migration plugin.
Can't upload relatively big files in WP File Manager as well. Small files work fine.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps if you are unable to clone your website to azure.

1. Install WordPress in the Azure.
2. Export only SQL database using All-In-One migration plugin.
3. Make a zip of the wp-content folder.
4. Upload the zipped wp-content folder to the Azure installation using the file manager of Azure.
5. Install the All-In-One Migration plugin in the Azure installation.
6. Import the exported `.wpress` file.